# How to silent install Postgresql in Ubuntu via. Dockerfile?

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile

I have the following docker file, and I am using the command `docker build -t demo:v1 .` to build the image.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
WORKDIR /app
RUN apt update \
    && apt -y upgrade \
    && apt install -y python3 \
    && apt install -y python3-pip \
    && apt install -y poppler-utils \
    && apt install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev

RUN apt install -y postgresql

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

CMD gunicorn -t 300 --workers 5 --bind  0.0.0.0:8080 wsgi
```

When I build an image using this, while installing postgresql, it expects input and stops the building process like this

```
.
.
.
.
Setting up libpopt0:amd64 (1.16-11) ...
Setting up tzdata (2019c-0ubuntu0.18.04) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Configuring tzdata
------------------

Please select the geographic area in which you live. Subsequent configuration
questions will narrow this down by presenting a list of cities, representing
the time zones in which they are located.

  1. Africa      4. Australia  7. Atlantic  10. Pacific  13. Etc
  2. America     5. Arctic     8. Europe    11. SystemV
  3. Antarctica  6. Asia       9. Indian    12. US
Geographic area:
```

So, how can I setup postgresql inside my image, so that it builds without expecting this input? Also, surprisingly, even after I input my option, nothing happens further, and the process gets stuck.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

add this to your Dockerfile

```
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

before installing `postgresql`

and I think you may want to use `apt-get` instead of `apt` to avoid this warning:

> WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in
> scripts.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I'll also change `apt` to `apt-get`. Does this `ARG` mean that Postgres will be installed with all default settings?

Comment: Yes that is correct, you need to edit the configs later using volumes or coping the files in dockerfile

Comment: Understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the answer by @LinPy , After adding ARG it worked for me.

Below is my Dockerfile content for further reference.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN  apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt update
RUN apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib -f -y
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `TZ` in the environment in the image to a specific value before the installation command as in:

```
ARG TZ=Etc/UTC
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y the_packages
```

or any other timezone if you don't want UTC